# fullcalendar set id issue

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar v6.1.10

```
    const calendarEl = document.querySelector(".custom_event_calendar");

    const calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        locale: 'de',
        initialView: "dayGridMonth",
        displayEventEnd: true,
        slotLabelFormat: {
            hour: "numeric",
            meridiem: "short",
            hour12: true
        },
        events:[ {
            id: '80185814',
            start: "2023-12-05T08:00",
            end: "2023-12-05T16:00",
            title: "Lorem"
        }],
        eventClick: function(event){
            console.log(event.el.id);
        }

    });
    calendar.render();
```

when I set ID to any event renders event with no id

I logged elements, but id is just empty

Also do that id will be set to event element as html attribute?

Comment: @0stone0 in a console, I use code below to log
`eventClick: function(event){console.log(event.el.id);}`
I get empty string in console
I also logged like that `console.log(event.el);`
here is what I have found in logged object: id:""

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `id` on an `event` is not to set the HTML id attribute. So you won't see that in the DOM.

It's used together with [`calendar.getEventById()`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-getEventById) to get the event by the given id.

---

To get the `id` through an `eventClick()` handler, you shouldn't log the `event.el.id` since that's the DOM element, which has no ID as explained above. But you'll need to log the `event.id` to get the FullCalendar Event Object.

```js
eventClick: function(event){
    console.log('Clicked on #', event.event.id);
}
```

---

The param passed to `eventClick` has the following:

| Name | Object |
| --- | --- |
| event | The associated [Event Object](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object). |
| el | The HTML element for this event. |
| jsEvent | The native JavaScript event with low-level information such as click coordinates. |
| view | The current [View Object](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/view-object). |

---

Small demo showing this;

- Click on the event to log the ID
- Uncomment last line to show the work of `getEventById()`

```js
const calendarEl = document.querySelector(".custom_event_calendar");

const calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    locale: 'de',
    initialView: "dayGridMonth",
    displayEventEnd: true,
    slotLabelFormat: {
        hour: "numeric",
        meridiem: "short",
        hour12: true
    },
    events:[ {
        id: '80185814',
        start: "2023-12-05T08:00",
        end: "2023-12-05T16:00",
        title: "Lorem"
    }],
    eventClick: function(event){
        console.log('Clicked on #', event.event.id);
    }
});
calendar.render();

const ev = calendar.getEventById('80185814');
// console.log(ev)
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@6.1.10/index.global.min.js'></script>
<div class='custom_event_calendar'></div>
```

Comment: I need this in my eventClick listener, I don't need to get them by ID, I need to get the event ID from the event

Comment: PLease see my edit.